# Counting methods

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, balls-in-bins

I would like to ask, if my intuitive understanding of how to count is correct. Please elaborate or correct me, if the below interpretation is not sound.

Should constructing a $r$-sample (unordered set) without replacement from a population of size $n$ be equivalent to allocating $r$ indist. balls to $n$ distinguishable cells? Atleast, that's how I picture it even visually.

Consider the random placement of $r$ balls in $n$ distinguishable cells.

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
& \text{No restriction} & \text{Cell can be at most singly-occupied} \\
\hline
r \text{ dist. balls} & n^r & (n)_r = n(n-1)\cdots(n-r+1)=\frac{n!}{r!}\\
r \text{ indist. balls} & {n + r - 1 \choose r} & {n \choose r}
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Yes, this is sound.